SolidJS Router can't detect App.jsx issues
I just learn js and SolidJS , please be patient with me. I follow tutorial from bejamas.io. He use Routes which doesnt support anymore, so I modified my code with the latest SolidJS Router documentation. Here is my code :
App.jsx :
    function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand>{/* <A href="/">Solid Movie</A> */}</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>
        <Route path="/" component={MovieList} />
        <Route path="/movie-details/:id" component={MovieDetails} />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

Here is my index.jsx :
const root = document.getElementById("root");

...

// function App() {
//   return <h1>Works</h1>;
// }

render(
  () => (
    <Router root={App} />

    // <App />
  ),
  root
);

My problem is Router can't recognise my App.jsx, my site just blank white with no error in console. But if change App in index to function App which I make inside the index.jsx like the one in the comment it works properly.
Also I've tried to move Router to App.jsx like this following code (this one also works):
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
          <Navbar.Brand>{/* <A href="/">Solid Movie</A> */}</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>
        {/* <Route path="/" component={() => <h1>Movie List Placeholder</h1>} /> */}
        <Router>
          <Route path="/" component={MovieList} />
          <Route path="/movie-details/:id" component={MovieDetails} />
        </Router>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

But, I need to use <A></A>, which work only inside Router, so I moved so that the Container inside the Router like this
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        ...
        <Router>
          <Route path="/" component={MovieList} />
          <Route path="/movie-details/:id" component={MovieDetails} />
        </Router>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

This one doesn't work too, my app just blank white screen. So what is the problem ? Thanks for the help

Are you using SolidStart? I can highly recommend the official tutorial: https://docs.solidjs.com/solid-start/getting-started (second chapter is routing)

You are using the Router API in a wrong way: The App component should return the Router. The router takes a layout component via its root prop:
function App() {
  return (
    <Router root={Layout}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Router>
  );
}

Here is a working demo:
import { Route, RouteSectionProps, Router } from "@solidjs/router";
import { Component } from "solid-js";
import { render } from "solid-js/web";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  )
};
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
  )
};

const Layout: Component<RouteSectionProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <main>
      <nav>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
      </nav>
      {props.children}
    </main>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router root={Layout}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Router>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.body);

In the layout component you can use either the <a> element or the <A> component. The latter allows the use of relative path to its parent.
